# Install FFMPEG-PHP in cpanel

Tags: php, ffmpeg-php

I am developing web application in which number of still images can create video. In that case I am using ffmpeg-php library. But I have shown that we have to add this library, it do not present in php extensions by default. So I am using reseller so I can install this library myself. But I don't know how to install it in cpanel. Can anybody help me in that case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need Shell access to the server. You can connect to your server using SSH client PuTTy.

After loggin in you can execute the Linux shell command to install php-FFmpeg :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg-php
```